# Sorting Filtered Data by Date

Tags: swiftui, ios15

I have some swiftUI logic that display entries by date and only displays the date if there is a change in date. It works great, thanks to: [Display Entry Date with Change in Orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71624700/display-entry-date-with-change-in-orientation). The one problem I have is displaying entries by order of date. For example, say someone enters some data that they forgot to enter 3 weeks ago. (My logic allows date entry with any date in the past.) This logic won't place the entry ahead of the entries posted in the last week.

Normally I could do a sort like this:

```
filteredArray = wdArray.sorted { (user1, user2) -> Bool in
            return user1.points > user2.points
        }

or 

filteredArray = wdArray.sorted(by: {$0.points < $1.points})
```

Here is the start of my class

```
class Withdrawal: ObservableObject {

    @Published var wdArray: [WdModel] {
        didSet {
            // save withdrawal entries
                if let encoded = try? JSONEncoder().encode(wdArray) { // save withdrawal entries
                UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: "wdBank")
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the logic that filters the entries by date (no sorting).

```
// creates a list of unique date entries
    // (goes through all elements, saves them in a set, checks if already in set)
    var uniqueBankDates: [String] {
        var seen: Set<String> = []
        return wdvm.wdArray.filter { seen.insert($0.wdDate.formatted(date: .abbreviated, time: .omitted)).inserted }
            .map {$0.wdDate.formatted(date: .abbreviated, time: .omitted) }
    }
```

So the bottom line is that I need help modifying uniqueBankDates to filter AND sort the sets by date (oldest entries first).  I would appreciate any help on this.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to "save" the elements in a set - you can just:

- turn the array into a `Set` by simply using `Set(array)`, this will remove the duplicates
- turn the `Set` back to an array by using `Array(yourSetHere)`
- sort it
- turn the array of dates into an array of strings

Here's what `uniqueBankDates` should look like (`WdModel` shall be conform to `Hashable`):

```
    var uniqueBankDates: [String] {
        Array(Set(wdvm.wdArray))                // This will remove duplicates, but WdModel needs to be Hashable
            .sorted { $0.wdDate < $1.wdDate }   // Compare dates
            .compactMap {
                $0.wdDate.formatted(date: .abbreviated, time: .omitted)    // Return an array of formatted the dates
            }
    }
```

Comment: Added the new uniqueBankDates and I'm now getting the error "Referencing instance method 'sorted()' on 'Sequence' requires that 'WdModel' conform to 'Comparable'. I was getting an error for Hashable--I fixed that, but how to I fix Comparable--Xcode asks if I want to add protocol stubs. I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: @GalenSmith: the `Comparable` protocol creates one function that tells Xcode how to know which `WdModel` is "higher" than the other, but we can avoid that by specifying how to sort the array. I have edited my answer, now `.sorted()` has the function that should do for you. I also realised that I had forgotten a `wdDate` inside the `.compactMap()`, so I corrected that too.

Comment: Thanks @HunterLion for all your work on this.