# Set not Removing Duplicate Dates

Tags: swiftui, ios15

I have a structure that displays entries sorted by date. The date is displayed once for all entries of the same date. The problem I have is that Set
is not removing duplicate dates. If I have two entries with the same date, I have two blocks in the view with same entries in each block. See my original post [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71700937/sorting-filtered-data-by-date) If I enter multiple entries with the same date, uniqueDates (looking with the debugger) shows the same number of elements with the same date.

My theory is that Array(Set(wdvm.wdArray)) is sorting on the complete unformatted date which includes the time or other variables in each element. Therefore it thinks all the dates are unique. Is there anyway to use formatted dates for sorting?

```
struct WithdrawalView: View {

    @StateObject var wdvm = Withdrawal()

    var uniqueDates: [String] {

        Array(Set(wdvm.wdArray))                // This will remove duplicates, but WdModel needs to be Hashable
           .sorted { $0.wdDate < $1.wdDate }   // Compare dates
           .compactMap {
                $0.wdDate.formatted(date: .abbreviated, time: .omitted)    // Return an array of formatted the dates
            }
    }


    // filters entries for the given date
    func bankEntries(for date: String) -> [WdModel] {
        return wdvm.wdArray.filter { $0.wdDate.formatted(date: .abbreviated, time: .omitted) == date }
    }

    var body: some View {

        GeometryReader { g in


            VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                
                WDTitleView(g: g)
                List {
                    if wdvm.wdArray.isEmpty {

                        NoItemsView()

                    } else {

                        // outer ForEach with unique dates
                        ForEach(uniqueDates, id: \.self) { dateItem in  // change this to sort by date
                            Section {
                                // inner ForEach with items of this date
                                ForEach(bankEntries(for: dateItem)) { item in

                                    wdRow(g: g, item: item)

                                }
                            } header: {
                                Text("\(dateItem)")
                            }
                        }.onDelete(perform: deleteItem)
                    }
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("Bank Withdrawals", displayMode: .inline)
```

Below is the class used by this module

```
struct WdModel: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {

    var id = UUID()
    var wdDate: Date        // bank withdrawal date
    var wdCode: String      // bank withdrawal currency country 3-digit code
    var wdBank: String      // bank withdrawal bank
    var wdAmtL: Double      // bank withdrawal amount in local currency
    var wdAmtH: Double      // bank withdrawal amount in home currency
    var wdCity: String
    var wdState: String
    var wdCountry: String
}


class Withdrawal: ObservableObject {

    @AppStorage(StorageKeys.wdTotal.rawValue) var withdrawalTotal: Double = 0.0

    @Published var wdArray: [WdModel]
       
    init() {

        if let wdArray = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: StorageKeys.wdBank.rawValue) {   
            if let decoded = try? JSONDecoder().decode([WdModel].self, from: wdArray) {
                self.wdArray = decoded
                return
            }
        }

        self.wdArray = []


    // save new withdrawal data    
func addNewWithdrawal(wdDate: Date, wdCode: String, wdBank: String, wdAmtL: Double, wdAmtH: Double, wdCity: String, wdState: String, wdCountry: String) -> () {

        self.withdrawalTotal +=  wdAmtH

        let item = WdModel(wdDate: wdDate, wdCode: wdCode, wdBank: wdBank, wdAmtL: wdAmtL, wdAmtH: wdAmtH, wdCity: wdCity, wdState: wdState, wdCountry: wdCountry)
        
        wdArray.append(item)

        if let encoded = try? JSONEncoder().encode(wdArray) { // save withdrawal entries
            UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: StorageKeys.wdBank.rawValue)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: one date.]
I am trying to display all entries of the same date under the one date. This example shows what I want but not the 3 copies of the date and entries.

Comment: The computed property `var uniqueDates: [String] {..}`, does remove duplicate dates in my tests.
 
Could you show the code for `WdModel` and `Withdrawal`,
 especially what are `wdvm.wdArray` and `.wdDate`

Comment: my understanding from https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/hashable. The `Set(wdvm.wdArray)` uses the hash from your own `WdModel`.
 So it compares your `WdModel` hash not just the Date in it.
Since you have `var id = UUID()` in  `WdModel`, all `WdModel` will be unique.

In other words `Set(wdvm.wdArray)` does not give you unique Dates, it
gives you unique `WdModel`.

Comment: @Workingdog I don't want every entry to be unique. I want all entries on the same date to be unique. I am seeing the same result as before--entering 3 entries with the same date shows 3 dates (all with today's date) each with the same 3 entries.

Comment: This tells me that uniqueDates is accepting each entry date as unique instead of one date with multiple entries.

Comment: ok, maybe I did not understand the question well enough. I'll look into it.

Comment: "...I want all entries on the same date to be unique...",
 what do you want to use to determine if the entries are unique
 for a given date. Currently they are unique because you have `var id = UUID()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `Set` to remove duplicate dates, try something like this:

```
var uniqueDates: [String] {
    Array(Set(wdvm.wdArray.map { $0.wdDate }))
        .sorted { $0 < $1 }
        .compactMap {
            $0.formatted(date: .abbreviated, time: .omitted)
        }
}
```

EDIT-3:

to `display` unique `bankEntries` for a given date, based on day, month and year of a date (not seconds,etc...):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var wdArray = [WdModel]()
    
    let frmt: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd, yyyy"
        return formatter
    }()
    
    func bankEntries(for date: String) -> [WdModel] {
        return wdArray.filter { frmt.string(from: $0.wdDate) == date }
    }

    var uniqueDates: [String] {
        Array(Set(wdArray.map { frmt.string(from: $0.wdDate) }))
            .sorted { frmt.date(from: $0) ?? Date() < frmt.date(from: $1) ?? Date() }
            .compactMap { $0 }
    }

    var body: some View {
        List {
            // outer ForEach with unique dates
            ForEach(uniqueDates, id: \.self) { dateItem in  // change this to sort by date
                Section {
                    // inner ForEach with items of this date
                    ForEach(bankEntries(for: dateItem)) { item in
                      //  wdRow(g: g, item: item)
                        HStack {
                            Text(item.wdDate.formatted(date: .abbreviated, time: .omitted))
                            Text(item.wdCode).foregroundColor(.red)
                        }
                    }
                } header: {
                    Text("\(dateItem)")
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            let today = Date()  // <-- here
            let otherDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 345678)
            
            wdArray = [
                WdModel(wdDate: today, wdCode: "EUR", wdBank: "Bank of Innsbruck", wdAmtL: 4575, wdAmtH: 1625, wdCity: "Innsbruck", wdState: " Tyrol", wdCountry: "Aus"),
                
                WdModel(wdDate: otherDate, wdCode: "CHF", wdBank: "Bank of Interlaken", wdAmtL: 6590, wdAmtH: 2305, wdCity: "Interlaken", wdState: "Bernese Oberland ", wdCountry: "CHF"),
                
                WdModel(wdDate: today, wdCode: "USD", wdBank: "Bank X", wdAmtL: 1200, wdAmtH: 3275, wdCity: "Las Vegas", wdState: "NV", wdCountry: "USA")
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: updated my answer with code that shows how to get all unique entries for a given date.

Comment: Another idea might be to save the date as a string, then use that in the sort functions.

Comment: I would recommend using `Date` for your dates, instead of using `String`.
 Comparing two strings as if they were dates will not work when sorting. You will endup 
 converting the `Strings` to `Dates` to do that.
 Note, you can adjust the equatable and hash functions, by selecting the properties 
 most relevant to your app. Does my test code work for you and answer 
 your question, "...I want all entries on the same date to be unique...."?

Comment: I'm still looking at the sample code. I see two dates with an x and z after them.

Comment: updated my answer with some test code to `display` unique bankEntries for a given date.

Comment: if you could show the 3 `WdModel` sample data that you display in the picture,
 I could try using those in my test code.

Comment: I added my function to display each row and re-ordered the onAppear data and the view shows two different dates with two entries under each date (correct).  When I then bring in my class and add 3 withdrawals uniqueDates shows 3 dates that are all the same (should be one) and the view show 3 dates and 3 entries each for 9 entries instead of 3. So it appears that Set() doesn't work correctly with my class.

Comment: WdModel(wdDate: Date(), wdCode: "EUR", wdBank: "Bank of Innsbruck", wdAmtL: 4575, wdAmtH: 1625, wdCity: "Innsbruck", wdState: " Tyrol", wdCountry: "Aus"),
                    WdModel(wdDate: otherDate, wdCode: "CHF", wdBank: "Bank of Interlaken", wdAmtL: 6590, wdAmtH: 2305, wdCity: "Interlaken", wdState: "Bernese Oberland ", wdCountry: "CHF"),
                    WdModel(wdDate: Date(), wdCode: "USD", wdBank: "Bank X", wdAmtL: 1200, wdAmtH: 3275, wdCity: "Las Vegas", wdState: "NV", wdCountry: "USA")

Comment: Updated my answer. 
You are getting the results you describe because the two `Date()` you use to make your `WdModel` data are different.
They may be only a few milliseconds different, but there are different.
If you use a constant `Date` such as in my updated answer, you will get the desired results.
 
 **However**, in view of what you are experiencing, I have modified `uniqueDates` to return unique dates
 based on the `day, month, year`. Included a `DateFormatter` and updated `bankEntries`.

Comment: Note:  you can of course add other criteria to compare dates, such minutes, seconds, milliseconds.
 Just modify the `DateFormatter`.

Comment: Thanks @workingdog support Ukraine for sticking around to get it working!